# How to manually validate JWT based on username in the url asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am trying to use asp.net identity framework for mvc and JWT for APIs. Requirement is that api accessing username/device is in the url, for example, api/v1/username/accounts. The user or the device that JWT was issues has username in it. Can I do it in the startup.cs file. The following code was working fine until recently then it started doing strange thing by allowing asp.net identity  to use JWT protected APIs. I want to check if username in the url api/v1/**username**/accounts matches the token one .Following is my code. Thanks for your insights.

```
 public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)

            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)

            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)

            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
             Configuration = builder.Build();

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()

            .MinimumLevel
            .Warning()
            .WriteTo.RollingFile("Logs/GateKeeperLog-{Date}.txt")
            .CreateLogger();
    }

    public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
        services.AddDbContext<GkEnterpriseContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Database:Connection"]));
        services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<GkEnterpriseContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        services.AddMvc()
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            }).AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

            });

        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddSerilog();
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

         app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("/api")

        , builder =>
        {
            builder.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
            {
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                AutomaticChallenge = true,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["Tokens:Audidence"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes
                        (JwtTokenIssuer.PrivateKey)),
                    ValidateLifetime = true,

                    NameClaimType = JwtRegisteredClaimNames.FamilyName
                }

            });

            app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api/v2/computers/")

                , builder1 =>

                    builder1.MapWhen((ctx) =>
                    {
                        var deviceName = ctx.User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Type == System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value ?? "";
                        var testPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString($"/api/v2/computers/{deviceName}");

                        var pathMatch = ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(testPath);
                        return String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(deviceName) || !pathMatch;

                    }, cfg =>
                    {
                        cfg.Run((req) =>
                        {
                            req.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                            return req.Response.WriteAsync("Sorry , you cant access this resource...");
                        });
                    }));


        });


        app.UseIdentity();
        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/StatusCodes/{0}");
        app.UseStaticFiles();


        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "defaultApi",
                template: "api/v2/{controller}/{id?}");
        });




    }
}
```

// JWT issung code block, it is now issuing tokens as expected, only validating is the problem.

```
 var claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub,computer),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.FamilyName,"GkDevice")
            };
            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PrivateKey));

            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: Startup.Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],
                audience: Startup.Configuration["Tokens:Audidence"],
                claims: claims,
                notBefore: DateTime.Now,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddYears(10),
                signingCredentials: creds
            );

            var data = new Token
            {
                Message = "New Token was issued",
                Jwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
                Iat = GkHelpers.ConvertTimeToEpoch(token.ValidFrom) ,
                Exp = GkHelpers.ConvertTimeToEpoch(token.ValidTo)
            };
            return data;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might help you --

```
app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api"), builder =>
{
    ...jwt code...
    builder.MapWhen((ctx) =>
    {
        var userName = ctx.User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Type == System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value ?? "";
        var testPath = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString($"/api/v2/computers/{userName}/");
        var pathMatch = ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(testPath);
        return String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName) || !pathMatch;
    }, cfg =>
    {
        cfg.Run((req) =>
        {
            req.Response.StatusCode = 403;
            return req.Response.WriteAsync("");
        });
    });
});
```

The inner `MapWhen` will trigger when the username in the "Name" claim (configure how to get the username here) does not match the given Path. It will then immediately execute the following request pipeline which will return a 403 code with an empty response body.

I am unsure, however, if you can process Identity-related items in the same request pipeline in which you actually *add* identity. You might have to extract that MapWhen code outside of the UseWhen.

Comment: I will try this , thank you. The use identity does not seem to work as expected. Api is accessible from jwt as well as from identity. Is it same authorize attributes on api controllers and mvc controllers could be doing it?

Comment: You'll want to look at your request pipeline as a whole and make sure that users aren't being authenticated somewhere else.

Comment: Hello  Stephen, the above solution is rejecting all requests, not even allowing to get to tokens controller, even it  is not protected with authorize attribute or may be I am doing it wrong. Can you help. Thank You

Comment: My implementation of this gets the username via claims. You need to replace the code that gets the username with whatever code you use, since I didn't see that.

Comment: My username is coming from jwt token , nothing from database. Username comes from url and then taking token from request and extract sub =username in that

Comment: Right what I mean is that you need to take username from the URL and then extract the username from the JWT token to compare it. My code does this from claims. Your code needs to do this however you choose. I tested this code by substituting _"bob"_ in userName, and `/api/v1/bob` works, while `/api/v1/tom` does not work.

Comment: I added the code and you advice, although the token's controller isnt decorated with [Authorize] but I cant still access it. 403 kicks in

Comment: Can you edit your main post with your entire Startup.cs/Configure method? I'm kind of shooting in the dark here.

Comment: Updated. THANK YOU. the actual api is api/v2/computers/"machineName here"/credentials

Comment: What you need to do is drop a debugger in the MapWhen line, on the return statement. You need to verify two things: that the userName is not null or empty, _and_ that the ctx.Request.Path field starts with `/api/v2/computers/{userName}/`. One of those conditions is failing.

Comment: it is correctly extracting  username from jwt but and username from url is same everytime and it goes into 403 block anyway.

Comment: I updated the code to kind of break up the logic inside the return clause. Try that out and see what's failing. The MapWhen should _only_ trigger with a blank/null userName *OR* when the userName is valid _and_ the path does not match.

Comment: Same issue its not get value from url, its only extracting it from JWT then that username is replaced in $"/api/v2/computers/{userName}/" . It does not allow to access tokens controller, so returning 403

Comment: What do you mean it's not getting the value from the URL? A URL consists of Schema(http://)Host(google.com)Path(/search/)Query(?term="kittens"). Your path (/api/v2/computers/userName) should start with the path we manually created.

Comment: var pathMatch = ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(testPath); is always returning false whether i use correct value or wrong one and then it enters into 403 block

Comment: Many Thanks dude. Its working now, the path wasnt matching because of that  / at the end. I wish I could figure out, why it doesnt get to tokens controller with me changing app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api/v2/computers") , so this excluding everything that comes before  /api/v2/computers and I can get to tokens controller, not a good choice though. I highly appreciate your help.

Comment: ctx.User.Claims.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Type == System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value ?? "" is always null

Comment: Replace that code with however you get the username from the JWT.

Comment: Thank youuuuuuuu Stephen.  It is working as expected;)

Comment: Hello Stephen, Since I upgrade from core 1x to 2, I managed to use jwt for api and cookies/identity for mvc, since core 2 change things around, i dont know where to put  app.UseWhen(context => context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api"), builder =>
{

Comment: It should be in the same location. Core 2.0 keeps much of the same layout for Startup.cs, the biggest ones being registering services and constructing your middleware.

Comment: JwtRegisteredClaimNames.GivenName is always null in configure method